# Calling sys_read two times [Nasm, Linux]

Tags: linux, io, nasm

Twice i try to read character from input, the first time "call getUserAction" works fine, but the main problem is, that the system didn't call the second read func, it just exits. Here is a little part of my code

```
SECTION .bss
        buffer resb 1
SECTION .text
    global _start
    _start:
    ...some unuseful and commented code
    call getUserAction ;reading 1 byte from console, works fine
    ...
    jmp count
    call exit
    count:
           ...
           call getUserAction; don't work, just exits from program without err
           ...commented code to debug
           call exit

    getUserAction: ;proc to read from console 1 byte
             mov eax, 3
             mov ebx, 0
             mov ecx, buffer
             mov edx, 1
             int 80h
             ret
```

Also i tried to put code from getUserAction in "count" proc, but it changes nothing.

**UPD:** Answer on first comment:
After the second "getUserAction":

```
 mov eax, [buffer]
 cmp eax, 'u'    
 je setUsersValues
 cmp eax, 'e'
 je callFunc     
 call exit
```

**UPD2**: I'm so sorry, here is all code

```
%define newline 10,0
%define A1 -7
%define A2 3
%define A3 2
%define A4 4
%define A5 2
SECTION .data
    labInfo     db "============Lab_3============",newline
    labInfoLen  equ $ - labInfo
    mainMenu    db "Choose the ex:",newline,\
            " r - call count",newline,\
            " t - call beep", newline,\
            " y - call exit func",newline
    mainMenuLen equ $ - mainMenu
    funcStr     db "Here func func func", newline
    funcStrLen  equ $ - funcStr
    countPromt  db "Please,choose the variant of variables value",newline,\
              " u - user defined values", newline,\
              " e - execerciese defined values", newline,\
              "Your choise:"
    promtLen    equ $ - countPromt
SECTION .bss
    buffer resb 1
    resultValue resb 1
%macro calculateFunc 5
     push eax
     push edx
     push ecx
         mov eax, %1
         mov ecx, %2
         add eax, ecx

         mov ecx, %3
         imul ecx

         mov ecx, %4
         xor edx, edx
         idiv ecx

         mov ecx, %5
         add eax, ecx
         mov [resultValue], eax
    pop ecx
    pop edx
        pop eax
%endmacro
SECTION .text
global _start
_start:
    ;call showPromt
    push labInfo
    push labInfoLen
    call printStr
    add esp, 8
    ;call showVarsList
    push mainMenu
    push mainMenuLen
    call printStr
    add esp, 8

    call getUserAction
    ;get get get action
    mov eax, [buffer]
    cmp eax, 'r'
    je count
    cmp eax, 't'
    je beep
    cmp eax, 'y'
    je exit
    jmp _start
count:
    ;showFuncInfo
    push funcStr
    push funcStrLen
    call printStr
    add esp, 8
    ;showProposal
    push countPromt
    push promtLen
    call printStr
    add esp, 8

    call getUserAction
    mov eax, [buffer]
    cmp eax, 'u'    
    je setUsersValues
    cmp eax, 'e'
    je callFunc 
    call exit
    ret
setUsersValues:
    nop; add some code later
        ret
callFunc:
    calculateFunc A1,A2,A3,A4,A5
    add byte [resultValue], '0'
    push resultValue
    push 1
    call printStr ; print Result
    add esp, 8
    ret
printStr:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, [ebp+12]
    mov edx, [ebp+8] 
    int 80h

    pop ebp
    ret 
getUserAction:
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, buffer
        mov edx, 1
    int 80h
    ret
beep:
     nop;add some code later
     ret
exit:
    mov eax, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 80h
```

Comment: and what is the code right above your second getUserAction?  For all we know, a pigeon is doing something to your code there...

Comment: Answered in UPD :) Sorry for this style, I asked a question here a fist time.

Comment: Seriously, you are leaving out way too much code for us to help fix.  What does setUsersValues look like?  callFunc?  all those could be the culprit.

Comment: without seeing all the code, your buffer should be at least 2 bytes.  the size for both sys_read and sys_write should be 2 not 1.

Comment: Just added all code, i'm apologize for making some troubles for u

Comment: @Gunner You was right, I increase in sys_call_read <mov edx, 1> read size to 2 - <mov edx, 2>, and in cmp instruction changed <cmp eax,'r'> to <cmp al, 'r'> and it works! Thanks you a lot :) How to mark this question as solved and your answer as the best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without seeing all the code, your buffer should be at least 2 bytes. the size for both sys_read and sys_write should be 2 not 1.

Comment: Thanks) And tell me, please, why at least 2 bytes? not 1?

Comment: need to take into account for the return key press/NULL